# Is it possible to close question with a bounty?

Tags: support, status-completed, vote-to-close, bounty

I just read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46917103/convert-persian-digits-to-english-and-convert-arabic-characters-to-persian), which is completely off-topic, was self-answered and there's an active bounty by the OP.

The question already has 3 close votes and we should be allowed to close it, specially since that bounty will auto-expire since you cannot award the bounty to yourself.

Can anything be done about it?

Comment: Definitely some funny smells coming from there. A great situation for a flag. Handled now.

Comment: @CodyS.Pumpkins Thanks, glad that I did the correct thing